# How to delete a Gerrit Repository without using delete Plugin?

Tags: git, gerrit

We do not have delete plugin installed in Gerrit. How can I delete my Gerrit Repository now. I have wrong data in the repository and I want to delete it and recreate the repository to push my new data. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What prevents you from installing the deleteproject plugin? It's the easiest way to safely remove projects.

Comment: Also see [how to install the delete-project plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254291/how-to-install-delete-project-plugin-in-gerrit).

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?  I have a very limited access to Gerrit and can't install plugins.

Answer (score -1):

There is not easy way to delete a gerrit from from web interface neither ssh command.
The easiest and recommend way is to use delete-project plugin as explain on [Delete a project in Gerrit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723716/delete-a-project-in-gerrit).

Otherwise, you have to find and delete all project references in gerrit database.